# How to convert efficiently dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am struggling to convert a dictionary to a pandas dataframe. The dictionary has the following structure, where keys in the embedded dictionaries corresponds to column names of the table:

```
d = {{key1:v1,key2:v2},{key1:v3,key2:v4}}
```

The dictionaries within the main dictionary correspond to a row

Expected output:

```
   key1   key2
0   v1     v2
1   v3     v4
```

I have been trying to use DataFrame.from_dict() but could not make it work with that structure. Any idea how to do that efficiently?

Many thanks

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(d)` ?

Comment: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

Comment: The specific format given in the question is incorrect and indicates a set of dictionaries which would be rejected as unhashable. If a dictionary was properly defined then it could be converted using the @idan noshul approach. Or if instead it was written as `d = [{key1:v1,key2:v2},{key1:v3,key2:v4}]` then it could be converted using the @jezrael approach.